# Creating email subscription service via SP 2010

Tags: list, email-templates

Is it possible to create an email subscription service in SharePoint 2010? We have an ASP.NET app where users sign up to receive a bi-weekly newsletter. Our SharePoint installation is currently internal only, but we wondered if we could perhaps have one section that's external for this purpose.

Users would sign up and receive an email with a confirmation link; once clicked, they'd be confirmed on the database as having a valid email address. Admin users would create the newsletter in SharePoint and send it to the list of subscribers.

Any thoughts on this? Also, can a SharePoint site have an internal and external parts? Any 3rd party modules you can recommend? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bamboo has a solution for group email.

http://store.bamboosolutions.com/p-40-group-email-web-part.aspx

There are a few others out there as well.

You can do this on your own with a couple of lists.  Use one to capture user information, and the other to store your items to send.  Create a workflow that uses the email addresses of the first list to send out newly added content items from the first.

Or, you could use a contact list, and use Outlook to manage your lists.

Additionally, you could use the alert functionality with custom alerts (assuming all users will have SharePoint logons).

You can always just keep your asp.net app going as well and just use the page viewer web part to surface it in SharePoint.

As you can see there are a number of ways to achieve what you want, I've only listed a handful here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure content deployment pathes to replicate changes between internet and intranet parts of your portal. This is standart SharePoint functionality, but it could be useful for you. Here is short [introduction to this area](http://milingon.com/blog/2011/introduction-to-sharepoint-content-deployment.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, KH Milingon. Didn't know you could do that. Very handy :)

Answer (score 0):

EnovaPoint also have a great and [simple to use group email / newsletter solution for SharePoint 2010 /2013 and SharePoint Online in Office 365](http://www.enovapoint.com/junglemail/sharepoint-group-email/).
You could also read a [review by Vlad Catrinescu of this product on sharepoint community website](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/review-of-junglemail-newsletter-and-group-email-solutio).

It could be used for internal and external purpose. There are subscription web part you want to have, also it supports sending newsletter according to topics people subscribed to. in email body and subject you can use the data you have in SharePoint autofilled (mail-merge functionality).